# How can I make plotly subplots the same size when converting from facets with ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

In `ggplot2` I believe the facets (subplots) are all the same size. I think this is very important for making comparisons between the subplots. However, when I convert my plots to plotly objects using `ggplotly()` the subplots are not always the same size. In particular, the rows seem to be different heights. I am not sure if this is the intended functionality of `ggplotly()`, a bug, or just user error on my part. I am using ggplot2 version 2.2.1.9000 and plotly 4.7.1.

**How can I convert my ggplots to plotly objects while ensuring the subplots are all the same size?**

Note: I originally posted this question in the context of using Shiny and plotly. However, the issue seems to be independent of Shiny so I am deleting my original question and reposting.

In the example below, when I use `facet_wrap(sex ~ day)` the second row is slightly shorter than top and bottom rows. When I use `facet_grid(sex ~ day)` the rows are equal in height. When I use `facet_grid(sex ~ day)` the two middle rows are slightly shorter.

```
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)

# An example plot
myPlot <- ggplot(tips, aes(x = total_bill, y = tip / total_bill)) +
  geom_point(shape = 1) 

# Facet wrap with sex ~ day
pWrap <- myPlot + facet_wrap(sex ~ day)
qWrap <- ggplotly(pWrap)

q <- qWrap
d <- rbind(q$x$layout$yaxis4$domain, q$x$layout$yaxis3$domain, q$x$layout$yaxis2$domain, q$x$layout$yaxis$domain)
dfWrap <- data.frame(lb = d[,1], ub = d[,2])
dfWrap["range"] <- dfWrap["ub"] - dfWrap["lb"]
dfWrap["facetType"] <- "facet_wrap(sex ~ day)"

# Facet grid with sex ~ day
pGrid1 <- myPlot + facet_grid(sex ~ day)
qGrid1 <- ggplotly(pGrid1)

q <- qGrid1
d <- rbind(q$x$layout$yaxis4$domain, q$x$layout$yaxis3$domain, q$x$layout$yaxis2$domain, q$x$layout$yaxis$domain)
dfGrid1 <- data.frame(lb = d[,1], ub = d[,2])
dfGrid1["range"] <- dfGrid1["ub"] - dfGrid1["lb"]
dfGrid1["facetType"] <- "facet_grid(sex ~ day)"

# Facet grid with day ~ sex
pGrid2 <- myPlot + facet_grid(day ~ sex)
qGrid2 <- ggplotly(pGrid2)

q <- qGrid2
d <- rbind(q$x$layout$yaxis4$domain, q$x$layout$yaxis3$domain, q$x$layout$yaxis2$domain, q$x$layout$yaxis$domain)

dfGrid2 <- data.frame(lb = d[,1], ub = d[,2])
dfGrid2["range"] <- dfGrid2["ub"] - dfGrid2["lb"]
dfGrid2["facetType"] <- "facet_grid(day ~ sex)"
```

## EDIT

After some more digging I found that the plotly uses the `get_domains()` function to define the layout. Inside this function there is a line for defining the heights of the plots

```
ys[[i]] <- c(ystart = 1 - (heights[j]) - if (j == 1) 0 else margins[3],
             yend = 1 - (heights[j + 1]) + if (j == nrows) 0 else margins[4])
```

such that the top and bottom rows are higher by the width of the margins. It appears the margins include not only the spacing between the panels (`panel.spacing`) but also room for axis labels, ticks, panel titles, etc. Therefore, we can find a test case that works reasonably well with `ggplot()` but totally fails with `ggplotly()`

```
p <- ggplot(data = tips %>% 
              group_by(time, sex, day) %>%
              summarize(total_bill = mean(total_bill)),
            aes(x = time, y = total_bill)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(sex ~ day, scales = "free_x") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))

ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: You could try specifying `aspect.ratio` in a theme() layer. That would hard code the same relative size for all of your plots?

Comment: @kfurlong The ggplot plot is already correct. I don't think aspect ratio is the issue. I just want the height of each facet row to be equal in plotly. For example, all rows of plots should be 2in high. Not some rows of 1.9in high plots.